# Data is not uploading on firebase in android studio

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

In my quiz admin panel app while I a upload a image and click upload button data is not being uploaded to my realtime database. It just shows uploading. And it doesn't show any error also.
I need help with this. Code is working properly till image upload and giving category name.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ActivityMainBinding binding;
    FirebaseDatabase database;
    FirebaseStorage storage;
    CircleImageView categoryImage;
    EditText inputCategoryName;
    Button uploadCategory;
    Dialog dialog;
    View fetchImage;
    Uri imageUri;
    int i=0;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null) {
            actionBar.hide();
        }

        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();

        dialog = new Dialog(this);
        ;
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.item_add_category_dialog);

        if (dialog.getWindow() != null) {

            dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
            dialog.setCancelable(true);
        }

        progressDialog=new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setTitle("uploading");
        progressDialog.setMessage("please wait");


        uploadCategory = dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_Upload);
        inputCategoryName = dialog.findViewById(R.id.inputCategoryName);
        categoryImage = dialog.findViewById(R.id.categoryImage);
        fetchImage = dialog.findViewById(R.id.fetchImage);


        binding.addCategory.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                dialog.show();
            }
        });

        fetchImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                intent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
            }
        });


        uploadCategory.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String name = inputCategoryName.getText().toString();

                if (imageUri == null) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please upload category image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if (name.isEmpty()) {
                    inputCategoryName.setError("Enter category name");
                } else {
                    progressDialog.show();
                    uploadData();
                }
            }
        });
    }

        private void uploadData() {

            final StorageReference reference = storage.getReference().child("category")
                    .child(new Date().getTime() + "");

            reference.putFile(imageUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    reference.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {

                            CategoryModel categoryModel = new CategoryModel();
                            categoryModel.setCategoryName(inputCategoryName.getText().toString());
                            categoryModel.setSetNum(0);
                            categoryModel.setCategoryImage(imageUri.toString());

                            database.getReference().child("categories").child("category"+i++)
                                    .setValue(categoryModel).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onSuccess(Void unused) {
                                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"data uploaded",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                                        }
                                    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

                                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                                        }
                                    });
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            if (requestCode == 1) {
                if (data != null) {
                    imageUri = data.getData();
                    categoryImage.setImageURI(imageUri);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: As you mentioned above question. You are uploading images to Firebase `Storage` or `Realtime` Database? You have not written the logic to upload images to Storage. First, code to upload the image to Firebase Storage and add a link to that image to the real-time database. Then you can easily access that image using their link.

Comment: If you set a breakpoint on each line of the code you shared, run the code in a debugger, and then check the value of each variable on each line, which is the **first** line that doesn't do what you expect it to do? And since this is for Android: The Android docs have a great page on [debugging your app](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug) to get you started with, including the section on [working with breakpoints](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug#breakPoints) and [inspecting varialbles](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug#variablesAndWatches).

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond using @.